# Count multiple criteria in separate columns - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following table and am trying to count the number of actions each user has performed.

```
----------------------------------
| ID | User         | Action     | 
----------------------------------
| 1  | BobDoe       | View       |
| 2  | BobDoe       | Edit       |
| 3  | JaneDoe      | Comment    |
| 4  | BobDoe       | Comment    |
| 5  | JohnSmith    | Edit       |
| 6  | JaneDoe      | Edit       |
| 7  | JohnSmith    | Comment    |
| 8  | BobDoe       | View       |
----------------------------------
```

Currently I use the following query to just get the number of edits, but I'm wanting to change it so it counts comments and views and displays them in their own columns, I have no clue how I'd go about counting them each separately without having to make an entirely new query.

`SELECT Type, User, COUNT(*) AS Num FROM some_database GROUP BY User`

Any ideas?

Comment: `Type` is is `Action`, sorry I had changed the name and forgot to update it in the example I posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this query that works in MySQL because `TRUE` is equivalent to 1 and `FALSE` is equivalent to  0:

```
SELECT
    User, 
    COUNT(*) AS Num,
    SUM(Action = 'Comment') AS NumComments,
    SUM(Action = 'View') AS NumViews
FROM some_table
GROUP BY User
```

Result:

```
User       Num  NumComments  NumViews
-------------------------------------
BobDoe     4    1            2       
JaneDoe    2    1            0       
JohnSmith  2    1            0
```

Comment: If the table is empty, `SUM(boolean)` will return `NULL`, not zero.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is group by both `User` and `Action` like this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS Num FROM some_database GROUP BY User, Action
```

That will return results like this:

```
----------------------------------------
| User         | Action     | Num | 
----------------------------------------
| BobDoe       | View       | 2   |
| BobDoe       | Edit       | 1   |
| JaneDoe      | Comment    | 1   |
| BobDoe       | Comment    | 1   |
| JohnSmith    | Edit       | 1   |
| JaneDoe      | Edit       | 1   |
| JohnSmith    | Comment    | 1   |
----------------------------------------
```

So it won't give the results in their own columns, but it will give the count for each user/action combo as its own row.

The nice thing about this solution is that it will scale to any number of actions (Edit, View, Comment, and any other actions you want in the future). If you don't need that scalability, @Mark Byers answer is the way to do it and return the counts as columns.